# Get the order of finished threads in a race simulation and the winner

Tags: multithreading

I'm writing a code simulating a race between multiple threads and print the winner of that race, the order of threads finished. 
I was able to determine the winner, but I can't figure out how to print the order of all threads finished.

Here is the code till now, Any Help!!

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Runner {
private static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);
private static String winner;

public static synchronized void finished(String threadName) {
    if (winner == null) {
        winner = threadName;
    }
    latch.countDown();

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        threadPool.submit(new raceTrack("Racer "+i));
    }
    threadPool.shutdown();
    threadPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    try {
        latch.await();
        System.out.println("The winner is : " + winner);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("No winner");
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

}
}



public class raceTrack implements Runnable {

 public String racerID;

public raceTrack(String id) {
    this.racerID = id;
}

@Override
public void run() {


    System.out.println(racerID);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
            Runner.finished(racerID);
        }
}

}
```

Comment: Start by replacing your single `winner` string with an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a list of thread names instead of just one String:

```
private static List<String> threadList;

public static synchronized void finished(String threadName) {
    threadList.add(threadName);
    latch.countDown();

}
```

You then can iterate through the list and determine order of threads. The winner is determined as list.get(0)

Comment: @MohamedKhaled You just iterate over this list and print each line. I assume i can do this by youself. Replace System.out.println("The winner is : " + winner); with for each loop